# GIthub repository not found error on Android Studio 2.1.2 after changing the repository

Tags: android-studio, github

I delete my old Github Repository (name: **RealmDemo**) and create the new repo with new name: **daftar-negatif-investasi**. I'm on Windows 10 and I have removed the old remote repository and added the new one using  the following command (using Git Bash):

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add https://github.com/masumo/daftar-negatif-investasi.git
```

But, Android Studio always give me this error message:

> Failed with error: fatal: repository
>   'https://github.com/masumo/RealmDemo.git/' not found

when I try to push into my Github repository.

I believe the remote repository already changed, because running `git remote -v` command give me this result:

```
origin  https://github.com/masumo/daftar-negatif-investasi.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/masumo/daftar-negatif-investasi.git (push)
```

It seems Android Studio still refers to the old repository. Any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my failure in identifying the working directory. After I refactor my project into the new name, somehow Git Bash application move the default working directory to the upper level. I didn't notice this and all those commands are executed against the upper level of my new project directory.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Open the /.git/config file and delete the lines:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/githubaccountname/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: I didn't find those lines on my gitconfig. Here is the full content: [gui]
 recentrepo = C:/Users/Kosumo/AndroidStudioProjects/DaftarNegatifInvestasi [user]
 email = mas.kosumo@gmail.com
 name = masumo

Comment: you say, when you pushing to your repo Android Studio gives error. Could you push it manually via command line?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. It was my stupidity... When I apply all those commands, it tuned out that I worked on another directory (two upper level of my project directory). Should I accept your answer or I just close this question?

Comment: @masu.mo: you can create your answer and accept it. Or should I create it?

Comment: @masu.mo: Great, then accept it by clicking "Accept As Answer". 
Horas dari medan :)

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote rm origin 
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/MyApplication.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `origin`

```
 git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: I tried to remove and add it again. It stil gave me the same error.